Trying to build a binomial tree with a node that shows default

I am looking to create a defaultable binomial tree in latex that is similar to the image uploaded. At each node it is possible for the stock to default (the stock price goes to zero). I have looked online and can't seem to create the defaultable branch
So far this is the code I have, but can't figure out how to add a 3rd branch to a binomial model
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,sloped]
    \matrix (tree) [%
      matrix of nodes,
      minimum size=1cm,
      column sep=3.5cm,
      row sep=1cm,
    ]
    {
          &   & S_{2,2}$ \\
          & S_{1,1}$  &   \\
      S_{0,0}$ &      & S_{2,0}$ \\
          & S_{1,-1}$ &   \\
          &   & S_{2,-2}$ \\
    };
    \draw[->] (tree-3-1) -- (tree-2-2) node [midway,above] {$p (1 - \lambda_t \Delta t)$};
    \draw[->] (tree-3-1) -- (tree-4-2) node [midway,below] {$(1-p) (1 - \lambda_t \Delta t)$};
    \draw[->] (tree-2-2) -- (tree-1-3) node [midway,above] {$p^2 (1 - \lambda_t \Delta t)^2$};
    \draw[->] (tree-2-2) -- (tree-3-3) node [midway,below] {$(1-p)p (1 - \lambda_t \Delta t)^2$};
    \draw[->] (tree-4-2) -- (tree-3-3) node [midway,above] {$(1-p)p (1 - \lambda_t \Delta t)^2$};
    \draw[->] (tree-4-2) -- (tree-5-3) node [midway,below] {$(1-p)^2 (1 - \lambda_t \Delta t)^2$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us the TeX code you have tried so far!

Welcome. // Can you please explain what a defaultable branch is or shell be? Do you mean a trinomial event (3 outcomes)?

Yes, a defaultable branch is a branch that implies the stock price drops to zero, so it is not a trinomial model. At each branch there is a chance that the stock drops to zero

According to the answers given so far ... please let us know your question, i.e. best EDIT it. Thank you

With some minor corrections (you want math nodes) it finally compiles ... but what is your question?

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,sloped]
    \matrix (tree) [%
      matrix of math nodes,
      minimum size=1cm,
      column sep=3.5cm,
      row sep=1cm,
    ]
    {
              &          & S_{2,2} \\
              & S_{1,1}  &   \\
      S_{0,0} &          & S_{2,0} \\
              & S_{1,-1} &   \\
              &          & S_{2,-2} \\
    };
    \draw[->] (tree-3-1) -- (tree-2-2) node [midway,above] {$p (1 - \lambda_t \Delta t)$};
    \draw[->] (tree-3-1) -- (tree-4-2) node [midway,below] {$(1-p) (1 - \lambda_t \Delta t)$};
    \draw[->] (tree-2-2) -- (tree-1-3) node [midway,above] {$p^2 (1 - \lambda_t \Delta t)^2$};
    \draw[->] (tree-2-2) -- (tree-3-3) node [midway,below] {$(1-p)p (1 - \lambda_t \Delta t)^2$};
    \draw[->] (tree-4-2) -- (tree-3-3) node [midway,above] {$(1-p)p (1 - \lambda_t \Delta t)^2$};
    \draw[->] (tree-4-2) -- (tree-5-3) node [midway,below] {$(1-p)^2 (1 - \lambda_t \Delta t)^2$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



I'd use Forest, but not right now. If this is what you want, I might try later. Whether it is what you want I'm not sure because it seems like a simple enough extension of the code you've already written, so what am I missing?
[Due to an Okular bug, 'is this what you want?' has a certain imaginative burden. Apologies for that.]
This is a simple adaption of MS-SPO's answer:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,sloped]
  \matrix (tree) [%
    matrix of math nodes,
    minimum size=1cm,
    column sep=3.5cm,
    row sep=1cm,
  ]
  {
            &          & S_{2,2} \\
            & S_{1,1}  &   \\
    S_{0,0} &          & S_{2,0} \\
            & S_{1,-1} &   \\
            &          & S_{2,-2} \\
            & Zero    & Zero \\
  };
  \draw[->] (tree-3-1) -- (tree-2-2) node [midway,above] {$p (1 - \lambda_t \Delta t)$};
  \draw[->] (tree-3-1) -- (tree-4-2) node [midway,below] {$(1-p) (1 - \lambda_t \Delta t)$};
  \draw[->] (tree-2-2) -- (tree-1-3) node [midway,above] {$p^2 (1 - \lambda_t \Delta t)^2$};
  \draw[->] (tree-2-2) -- (tree-3-3) node [midway,below] {$(1-p)p (1 - \lambda_t \Delta t)^2$};
  \draw[->] (tree-4-2) -- (tree-3-3) node [midway,above] {$(1-p)p (1 - \lambda_t \Delta t)^2$};
  \draw[->] (tree-4-2) -- (tree-5-3) node [midway,below] {$(1-p)^2 (1 - \lambda_t \Delta t)^2$};
  \foreach \i/\j in {3-1/6-2,2-2/6-3,4-2/6-3} \draw [dotted,->,gray] (tree-\i) -- (tree-\j);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

From community:

